# Convert Byte stream into PDF, html, css files in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, ipad, ios5

Using .NET Web Service, which sends me response as Byte Stream(Table Data), these are HTML, PDF, CSS, JS,PNG etc files. I have established URL connection and trying to save the NSData in the local path:

```
NSString *writeableDBPath = [DOCUMENTS_FOLDER stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:writeableDBPath  contents:webData attributes:nil];
```

When I try to access test.pdf, it throws an error "test.pdf could not be open", when I try the same code by giving the actual path without using the Web Service I am able to access the PDF.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried and where are you getting stuck?  Don't say nothing and nowhere in particular...or no one will help you.

Comment: NSString *writeableDBPath = [DOCUMENTS_FOLDER stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];
 
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:writeableDBPath  contents:webData attributes:nil];
I have set up the URL connection, then I am trying save the NSData. When I try to access that pdf from the Libray, I get an error test.pdf could not open.                                  When I try to do the same by giving the actual PDF file from my disk I am able to download and access that particular PDF. Since the Web Service response is Byte Stream, I am stuck how to convert to PDF, etc.

Comment: Edit your question with this info and format it nicely.

Comment: Have edited the question, do u have any solution for this? If so, please let me know.

Comment: Please add code formatting to your code sections (indent four spaces for every line of code).  There are many unknowns in your code.  Can you verify the data that you are getting?  Can you verify that the file is being saved correctly?  What do you mean by "giving the actual path without using the Web Service"?

Comment: Sure will indent, actual path is calling PDF which is hosted in your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve this issue. The file was corrupted when it was sent from the Web Service.